# how do I find the closest value to a given number in an array?

Tags: matlab

The Situation is as follows:

I have to arrays, symbolizing a positive domain `x`, and another array whose a function of that domain `z`

Now, I want, for a given point `y`, to find the `z` value in the nearest location. For thatI wrote the following function:

```
R0 = @(y) z(find(abs( abs(y). -  r) == min(abs(abs(y). - r))))
```

(The use of `abs` is for negative values of `y`, since `z` is symmetric)

This works perfectally well, unless `y` is a vector. So, if I use the following code:

```
y = [-1:0.01:1];
R0(y);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Trying to debug it, I came to see that the `find` statement returned a 1*0 matrix, hence nothing. This is although the value of `y` ACTUALLY EXSIST in the `r` array.

What I really want is to get a new vector, which assign the nearest value in `z` for each value of `y`.

Other, totally different solutions might be used, so I prefer understanding why this solution doesn't work and how can I make it work.

Thanks

Comment: I get a `Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.` because of the `. -`. Is it `.'-` or `-`?

Comment: `.-` is what I've written there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. If I understand correctly, for each element of `y` you want to find the closest element in `z`.

```
y = [1 2 3 4 5]; %// example data
z = [0 2.5 6]; %// example data
d = abs(bsxfun(@minus, y(:).', z(:))); %'// compute distance for all pairs
[~, ind] = min(d); %// index of minimizer in z for each value of y
result = z(ind);
```

In this example,

```
result =
        0    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000    6.0000
```

Comment: Thnx, helped me alot. what is the `[~,ind]` syntax you're using?

Comment: @user42864: `min` returns two parameters.  The first parameter returns the minimum of the array and the second parameter returns the **location** of where this minimum occurs.  The `~` simply trashes the first parameter - It's not storing it into a variable as we don't need it.  For the second parameter, Luis Mendo is taking this index of where the minimum occurs to access the `z` array.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that all of `r,z,y` are row vectors;

According to the code you provided, it looks like you need the value in `z` whose index is same as the index of the value in `r` closest to `scalar y`. The following code does the same for a row vector `y`.

```
function output = some_fun(r,z,y)
    %// column i of temp is abs(r - y(i))
    temp = abs(repmat(abs(y),size(r,2),1) - repmat(r',1,size(y,2))) % // it is a size(r,2) x size(y,2) matrix
    %// each column i of min_ has min(abs(r - y(i))) as all its entries
    min_ = repmat(min(temp),size(r,2),1);  % // it is a size(r,2) x size(y,2) matrix
    %// each column i of ind1 has value of 1 corresponding to the index of closest element of r to y(i) and zero for others
    ind1 = temp == min;
    %// row_(i) is the row index of ind1 where the value is 1 for column i in ind1.
    [row_ col_] = find(ind1);
    %// thus row_(i) is the index of element of r closest to y(i)
    output = z(1,row_);
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Can you shed a bit of light on what you do here?

Comment: @user42864 See the explanation, ask if you need more detail

Comment: got it , thanks. I wonder why there isn't a simple one-line implementation to it.

Comment: @Nishant: Good approach, but Luis Mendo's `bsxfun` approach essentially performs this under the hood.