# replace a pandas series with the closest values from another series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series A, e.g. `1.3, 4.5, 10.11` and a series B `0.8, 5.1, 10.1, 0.3`, and I would like to get a series C with the closest number from A for every element in B: `1.3, 4.5, 10.11, 1.3`

btw, if it simplifies things the `closest` number from A can be the closest number **larger** than the number in B, so the answer can also be `1.3, 10.11, 10.11, 1.3`

related to 
[How do I find the closest values in a Pandas series to an input number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112202/how-do-i-find-the-closest-values-in-a-pandas-series-to-an-input-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Setup**

```
A = pd.Series([1.3, 4.5, 10.11])
B = pd.Series([0.8, 5.1, 10.1, 0.3])
```

**Option 1**
Use `pd.Series.searchsorted`
This searches through `A` for each element of `B` and finds where in `A` that element of `B` should be inserted.

```
A.iloc[A.searchsorted(B)]

0     1.30
2    10.11
2    10.11
0     1.30
dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 2**
But to get at the nearest, you could hack the `pd.Series.reindex` method.

```
pd.Series(A.values, A.values).reindex(B.values, method='nearest')

0.8      1.30
5.1      4.50
10.1    10.11
0.3      1.30
dtype: float64
```

Comment: method 1 fails on `positional indexers are out-of-bounds` if `B = pd.Series([0.8, 5.1, 10.1, 0.3, 30])`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the reindex method, but having non-unique values in series A throws up an error.

```py
A = pd.Series([1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 4.0, 5.0, 19.0, 20.0])
B = pd.Series([0.8, 5.1, 10.1, 0.3, 5.5])
pd.Series(A.values, A.values).reindex(B.values, method='nearest')

ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
```

This was the workaround that I believe could be useful to others.

```py
A = pd.Series([1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 4.0, 5.0, 19.0, 20.0])
B = pd.Series([0.8, 5.1, 10.1, 0.3, 5.5])
pd.Series(A.values, A.values).sort_index().drop_duplicates().reindex(B.values, method='nearest')

0.8      1.0
5.1      5.0
10.1    10.0
0.3      1.0
5.5      5.0
dtype: float64
```