# Python Pandas Dataframe - compute difference between rows and take the minimum one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas `Dataframe` `D` storing a large database. I also have a smaller `DataFrame` `C` with 10 rows, containing exactly the same columns as the main one, including column '`price`'. For each row `r` in the main dataframe `D` I want to find a row `t` in `C` which is closest, i.e., the difference between `r.price` and `t.price` is minimal. 
As an output I want to have:

I have a function computing the difference

```
def difference(self, row1, row2):
    d = np.abs(row1["price"] - row2["price"])
    return d
```

And I want to use apply function to apply the difference function to each row in C, for each row v in D:

```
for _, v in D.iterrows():
    C.apply(self.difference, axis=1, args=(v,))
```

But I don't know how I should find the row of `C` for which the difference was minimal. I was thinkking about the `min` build-in function from Python, but I don't know how to apply it correctly for dataframes.

An example: 
Let say I have a data D

```
    id | name | price
1.  bdb | AAA | 2.34
2.  441 | BBB | 3.56
3.  ae9 | CCC | 1.27
4.  fb9 | DDD | 9.78
5.  e6b | EEE | 5.13
6.  bx4 | FFF | 6.23
7.  a9a | GGG | 9.56
8.  847 | HHH | 9.23
9.  e4c | III | 0.45
...
200. eb3 | XYZ | 10.34
```

And C (for simplicity with just 5 rows) as below

```
    id | name | price
1.  xyh | AA1 | 0.34
2.  y5h | BB1 | 9.77
3.  af6 | CC1 | 3.24
4.  op9 | DD1 | 6.34
5.  23h | EE1 | 0.20
```

So, the output of my function should be as follows:

```
Row bdb in D should be matched with row af6
Row 441 in D should be matched with row af6
Row ae9 in D should be matched with row xyh 
Row fb9 in D should be matched with row y5h
Row e6b in D should be matched with row op9
etc.
```

Comment: I can't understand your problem without some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the closest values in a Pandas series to an input number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112202/how-do-i-find-the-closest-values-in-a-pandas-series-to-an-input-number)

Comment: @coldspeed I added a simply example

Comment: @Ziva Thanks. One more question. Does order matter?

Comment: @coldspeed No, I does not

Comment: Last one. I think your 441 row should match with af6. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.searchsorted` to index into a sorted version of `C.price`.

```
p1 = D.price.values

v = np.sort(C.price.values)
p2 = v[np.searchsorted(v, p1) - 1]

p2
array([ 0.34,  3.24,  0.34,  9.77,  3.24,  3.24,  6.34,  6.34,  0.34])
```

Now, subtract them `p2` from `p1`.

```
pd.Series(p1 - p2)

0    2.00
1    0.32
2    0.93
3    0.01
4    1.89
5    2.99
6    3.22
7    2.89
8    0.11
dtype: float64
```