# Get index of value (with conditions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I tried different options but I always return to the `.get_loc` function. I got a big data frame and need to find the row index of a value `nearest` or `backfill`. The df looks like this:

```
     Date     Product     Price
 0   1/1      NEG         3
 1   1/1      NEG         3.3
 2   1/1      NEG         5.1
 3   1/1      POS         1.4
 4   1/1      POS         3.7
 5   1/1      POS         3.9
 6   1/1      POS         4.6
 7   1/2      NEG         1.2
 8   ...      ...         ...
```

`df.columns.get_loc('Price')` gives me `2` for the index of the column 'Price', but I need the index of a special row by section ('Date' and 'Product'), e.g:

`df.loc[(df)['Date']=='1/1' & (df['Product']=='NEG')]`

now, search **Price == 3.4**:

`pd.Index(df.Price).get_loc(3.4, 'nearest')`

This would give me index=1, but it does not work because data is to big, there are multiple '3.4'.

Is there any way to search for the *nearest* value with certain conditions, like above?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

I'm not a fan of using .get_loc() so here's an alternative method to get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd

num = 3.4

# New dataframe fit_criteria for conditions (df['Date']=='1/1') & (df['Product']=='NEG')
fit_criteria = df.loc[(df['Date']=='1/1') & (df['Product']=='NEG')]

# Find absolute difference between values in price column and num. Find the index of
# the smallest difference using .idxmin()
nearest_to_num = (fit_criteria['Price']-num).abs().idxmin()

# Final result is the index of nearest number to num
nearest_to_num
```

If the comments aren't sufficient, here's a more verbose explanation of what's going on:

1. First we define the number we want to find the nearest number to with

   ```
   num = 3.4
   ```
2. Next we create a dataframe that fits the criteria of `Date = 1/1`
   and `Product = Neg` by passing them as conditions in `.loc[]`.

   ```
   fit_criteria = df.loc[(df['Date']=='1/1') & (df['Product']=='NEG')]
   ```
3. We then generate a dataframe of the absolute difference between
   `num` and the values in the column `price`. Finally the `.idxmin()`
   method is used which returns the index of the first minimum value

   ```
   nearest_to_num = (fit_criteria['Price']-num).abs().idxmin()
   ```
4. At the end of all this, `nearest_to_num` has a value of `1`,
   corresponding to the index of the row you want.

Do note that this approach does not account for multiple values that are equally near to `num`. I hope this answers your question sufficiently but feel free to let me know if you require more details or clarification.

---

Reference used:
[How do I find the closest values in a Pandas series to an input number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112202/how-do-i-find-the-closest-values-in-a-pandas-series-to-an-input-number)

Comment: thanks for the answer! I just added `(df['Price'] > num)` to the fit_criteria df and called the needed index with `index = fit_criteria.index.values.astype(int)[0] `. In that way I also get `backfill` (first) value with these conditions. Or do you know how to do it in a more elegant way? Anyway, I will try it now, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with any shorter way to achieve the same result. Sorry!