# Find closely matching value index in a Dataframe column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame of float numbers. I want to find closely matching number index.

```
df = 
index    value
0          10.53
1          20.23
2          12.34          
3          34.12
4          5.67
5          19.56
```

I want to find the closely matching value index for 9.5

```
matc_idx = df['value'].index.get_loc(9.5)
```

Output:

```
KeyError:
```

How to find the closely matching index. In this case, I am expecting

```
print(matc_idx) 
0
```

Previously accepted answers have used `ix` which is depreciated.

Comment: `df.iloc[(df['value']-9.5).abs().argsort()[:1]].index` from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112202/how-do-i-find-the-closest-values-in-a-pandas-series-to-an-input-number)

Comment: @politicalscientist I tried your method and got following response `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'argsort'`

Comment: sorry if I missed something. I replicated your df and run said code, it worked as expected, so not sure what's the problem :(

Comment: `df['value'].sub(9.5).abs().sort_values().index[0]` or `df['value'].sub(9.5).abs().idxmin()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) to get the closest [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

```
VAL = 9.5
((df['value'] - VAL)**2).idxmin()
```

Outputs

```
 0
```

Comment: your method worked.

Comment: Not sure why euclidean distance is required.  Surely absolute differences would suffice. In any event, `idxmin` would still work in either case.

Comment: @Alexander for 1D, absolute difference is the euclidean ;p I just mentioned euclidean for R^N solutions - of course I omitted `sqrt` here to avoid redundancies