# Pandas DataFrames: Efficiently find next value in one column where another column has a greater value

Tags: python, pandas

The title describes my situation. I already have a working version of this, but it is very inefficient when scaled to large DataFrames (>1M rows). I was wondering if anyone has a better idea of doing this.

**Example with solution and code**

Create a new column `next_time` that has the next value of time where the `price` column is greater than the current row.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90], 'price': [10.00, 10.01, 10.00, 10.01, 10.02, 9.99]})
print(df)
   time  price
0    15  10.00
1    30  10.01
2    45  10.00
3    60  10.01
4    75  10.02
5    90   9.99

series_to_concat = []
for price in df['price'].unique():
    index_equal_to_price = df[df['price'] == price].index
    series_time_greater_than_price = df[df['price'] > price]['time']
    time_greater_than_price_backfilled = series_time_greater_than_price.reindex(index_equal_to_price.union(series_time_greater_than_price.index)).fillna(method='backfill')

    series_to_concat.append(time_greater_than_price_backfilled.reindex(index_equal_to_price))

df['next_time'] = pd.concat(series_to_concat, sort=False)

print(df)
   time  price  next_time
0    15  10.00       30.0
1    30  10.01       75.0
2    45  10.00       60.0
3    60  10.01       75.0
4    75  10.02        NaN
5    90   9.99        NaN
```

This gets me the desired result. When scaled up to some large dataframes, calculating this can take a few minutes. Does anyone have a better idea of how to approach this?

**Edit: Clarification of constraints**

We can assume the dataframe is sorted by time.
Another way to word this would be, given any row **n** (Time_**n**, Price_**n**), 0 <= n <= len(df) - 1, find **x** such that Time_**x** > Time_**n** AND Price_**x** > Price_**n** AND there is no **y** such that **n** < **y** < **x** with Price_**y** > Price_**n**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David did come up with a great solution for finding the **closest** greater price at a later time. However, I did want to find the very next occurrence of a greater price at a later time though. Working with a coworker of mine, we found this solution.

Stack containing tuples (index, price)

1. Iterate through all rows (index i)
2. While the stack is non-empty AND the top of the stack has a lesser price, then pop and fill in the popped index with times[index]
3. Push (i, prices[i]) onto the stack

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90], 'price': [10.00, 10.01, 10.00, 10.01, 10.02, 9.99]})
print(df)
   time  price
0    15  10.00
1    30  10.01
2    45  10.00
3    60  10.01
4    75  10.02
5    90   9.99

times = df['time'].to_numpy()
prices = df['price'].to_numpy()
stack = []
next_times = np.full(len(df), np.nan)
for i in range(len(df)):
    while stack and prices[i] > stack[-1][1]:
        stack_time_index, stack_price = stack.pop()
        next_times[stack_time_index] = times[i]
    stack.append((i, prices[i]))
df['next_time'] = next_times

print(df)
   time  price  next_time
0    15  10.00       30.0
1    30  10.01       75.0
2    45  10.00       60.0
3    60  10.01       75.0
4    75  10.02        NaN
5    90   9.99        NaN
```

This solution actually performs very fast. I am not totally sure, but I believe the complexity would be close to **O(n)** since it is one full pass through the entire dataframe. The reason this performs so well, is the stack is essentially sorted, where the largest prices will be at the bottom, and the smallest price is at the top of the stack.

Here is my test with an actual dataframe in action

```
print(f'{len(df):,.0f} rows with {len(df["price"].unique()):,.0f} unique prices ranging from ${df["price"].min():,.2f} to ${df["price"].max():,.2f}')
667,037 rows with 11,786 unique prices ranging from $1,857.52 to $2,022.00

def find_next_time_with_greater_price(df):
    times = df['time'].to_numpy()
    prices = df['price'].to_numpy()
    stack = []
    next_times = np.full(len(df), np.nan)
    for i in range(len(df)):
        while stack and prices[i] > stack[-1][1]:
            stack_time_index, stack_price = stack.pop()
            next_times[stack_time_index] = times[i]
        stack.append((i, prices[i]))
    return next_times

%timeit -n10 -r10 df['next_time'] = find_next_time_with_greater_price(df)
434 ms ± 11.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice! I think this is a great problem that has been solved. It's also a perfect example of how a one-liner in pandas doesn't necessarily mean it will be scalable, making the problem significantly more complicated and having to come up with a unique, creative solution.

Answer (score 1):

These solutions were faster when I tested with `%timeit` on this sample, but I tested on a larger dataframe and they were much slower than your solution. It would be interesting to see if any of the 3 solutions are faster in your larger dataframe. I would look into `dask` or check out: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html

I hope someone else is able to post a more efficient solution. Some different answers below:

---

1. You can achieve this with a `next` one-liner that loops through both the `time` and `price` columns simultaneously with `zip`. The `next` function works exactly the same as a list comprehension, but you use need to parentheses instead of brackets, and it only returns the first `True` value. You also need to pass `None` to handle errors as a parameter within in the `next` function.
2. You need to pass `axis=1`, since you are comparing column-wise.

This should speed up performance, as you don't loop through the entire column as the iteration stops after returning the first value and moves to the next row.

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90], 'price': [10.00, 10.01, 10.00, 10.01, 10.02, 9.99]})
print(df)
   time  price
0    15  10.00
1    30  10.01
2    45  10.00
3    60  10.01
4    75  10.02
5    90   9.99

df['next_time'] = (df.apply(lambda x: next((z for (y, z) in zip(df['price'], df['time'])
                                            if y > x['price'] if z > x['time']), None), axis=1))
df
Out[1]: 
   time  price  next_time
0    15  10.00       30.0
1    30  10.01       75.0
2    45  10.00       60.0
3    60  10.01       75.0
4    75  10.02        NaN
5    90   9.99        NaN
```

As you can see list comprehension would return the same result, but in theory will be a lot slower... as the total number of iterating would increase significantly especially with a large dataframe.

```
df['next_time'] = (df.apply(lambda x: [z for (y, z) in zip(df['price'], df['time'])
                                       if y > x['price'] if z > x['time']], axis=1)).str[0]
df
Out[2]: 
   time  price  next_time
0    15  10.00       30.0
1    30  10.01       75.0
2    45  10.00       60.0
3    60  10.01       75.0
4    75  10.02        NaN
5    90   9.99        NaN
```

---

Another Option creating a function with some `numpy` and np.where():

```
def closest(x):
    try:
        lst = df.groupby(df['price'].cummax())['time'].transform('first')
        lst = np.asarray(lst)
        lst = lst[lst>x] 
        idx = (np.abs(lst - x)).argmin() 
        return lst[idx]
    except ValueError:
        pass


df['next_time'] = np.where((df['price'].shift(-1) > df['price']),
                            df['time'].shift(-1),
                            df['time'].apply(lambda x: closest(x)))
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your quick response! I see what you mean, with the smaller dataframe, I can definitely see why the apply is faster. I was trying to avoid an apply when I was initially making this, but realized quickly it was a tough problem to come up with a vectorized solution for. I'm going to run a test with one of the large dataframes and I'll update you on the performance.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if I could use most of the things in the Enhancing Performance link, but I have thousands of these large dataframes I need to calculate this for, so I'm already doing that in parallel

Comment: Following up: I ran this on a dataframe with ~660,000 rows and ~12,000 unique prices. My function took about 5 minutes to run, and and the first of your 3 has been running for 20 minutes and still has not returned. That's not a big deal at all. I'm curious about the np.where solution and I'll continue this in the next comment.

Comment: I think it's mostly due to a large number of unique prices. Your numpy where solution interests me. Maybe if I can partition this out into 3 cases where the next price is greater, next price is the same, and next price is lower, there could be some clever things there. I don't think there's an easy way of solving this with vectorized functions as a whole, but maybe the problem can be broken down into different cases.

Comment: Thanks @DamianVu very interesting question that you asked, so try my new solution, which is extremely fast and worked for a couple of different scenarios that I tries on 1 million rows in less than 7 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This one returned a variation of your dataframe with 1,000,000 rows and 162,000 unique prices for me in less than 7 seconds. As such, I think that since you ran it on 660,000 rows and 12,000 unique prices, the increase in speed would be 100x-1000x.

The added complexity of your question is the condition that the closest higher price must be at a later time. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553226/6366770 helped me discover the `bisect` functions, but it didn't have your added complexity of having to rely on a time column. As such, I had to tackle the problem from a couple of different angles (as you mentioned in a comment regarding my `np.where()` to break it down into a couple of different methods).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90], 'price': [10.00, 10.01, 10.00, 10.01, 10.02, 9.99]})

def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo


def get_closest_higher(df, col, val):
    higher_idx = bisect_right(df[col].values, val)
    return higher_idx


df = df.sort_values(['price', 'time']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['next_time'] = df['price'].apply(lambda x: get_closest_higher(df, 'price', x))

df['next_time'] = df['next_time'].map(df['time'])
df['next_time'] = np.where(df['next_time'] <= df['time'], np.nan, df['next_time'] )
df = df.sort_values('time').reset_index(drop=True)
df['next_time'] = np.where((df['price'].shift(-1) > df['price'])
                           ,df['time'].shift(-1),
                           df['next_time'])
df['next_time'] = df['next_time'].ffill()
df['next_time'] = np.where(df['next_time'] <= df['time'], np.nan, df['next_time'])
df

Out[1]: 
   time  price  next_time
0    15  10.00       30.0
1    30  10.01       75.0
2    45  10.00       60.0
3    60  10.01       75.0
4    75  10.02        NaN
5    90   9.99        NaN
```

Comment: Hey David, sorry for the late response, but I took a look and it is much faster, but still doesn't quite give me exactly what I would expect. Your solution finds the next price/time where the next price is the very next when ordered. However, I want to find where any price is greater at a later time, e.g. times = [15, 30, 45], prices= [10.00, 10.02, 10.01], the next time in the first row will find 45 instead of finding 30, since it is looking for 10.01.

In other words, I'm not looking for the closest next price, just any greater price at the closest time.

Comment: I really appreciate the help David. I believe I've come up with a solution that does this very fast actually, and I'll post my own solution in case anyone needs help in the future with this