# Find the closest values in a sorted pandas dataframe to values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, indexing

I have seen :

[How do I find the closest values in a Pandas series to an input number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112202/how-do-i-find-the-closest-values-in-a-pandas-series-to-an-input-number)

I have a pandas DataFrame like this :

| idx | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 56 |
| 2 | 3 | 22 |
| 3 | 6 | 12 |
| 4 | 7 | 7 |
| 5 | 7.5 | 6 |
| 6 | 9 | 9 |
| 7 | 10.1 | 11 |
| 8 | 11 | 23 |

and an input list like this :

[ 4, 7.6, 10]

I want to keep the same number of rows as the list length, where the elements in df['col1'] are the closest to the elements in the list such that y output DataFrame is :

| idx | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 22 |
| 5 | 7.5 | 6 |
| 7 | 10.1 | 11 |

What is an efficient solution when dataframe and list get big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in numpy to obtain the differences and then get the index conaininng the minimum absolute value

```
a = np.array([4,7.6,10]).reshape(1,-1) #np.array([[4,7.6,10]])
df.iloc[abs(df.col1.to_numpy()[:,None] - a).argmin(0)]

   idx  col1  col2
1    2   3.0    22
4    5   7.5     6
6    7  10.1    11
```

Answer (score 1):

There's `merge_asof` for matching sorted data:

```
pd.merge_asof(pd.DataFrame({'key':inpt}), df, 
              right_on='col1', left_on='key',
              direction='nearest')
```

Output:

```
    key  idx  col1  col2
0   4.0    2   3.0    22
1   7.6    5   7.5     6
2  10.0    7  10.1    11
```

Comment: Note that _inpt_ must be a list, such as [4.0, 7.6, 10.0] in this case.   
For more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 0):

First method is by substraction but have you considered the solution using partitionning in the topic you mentionned?