# pandas find closest value from other column to entire column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns of numbers:

| index | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | 0.55 |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| 3 | 0.8 | 0.35 |
| 4 | 1 | 0.9 |

I want to find tuples of the indexes of the closest values.
For example for this dataframe I would want the result

(0,2), (1,1), (2,3), (3,4), (4,4)

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112202/how-do-i-find-the-closest-values-in-a-pandas-series-to-an-input-number) link explaining how to do this for a given input, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this for my task.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try list comprehension if you are not working with a huge dataset. Subtract (`.sub()`) each x value from each y value, get the absolute value (`.abs()`) and then get the int position of the smallest value in the Series (`.argmin()`).

```
l = [(idx, df['Y'].sub(x).abs().argmin()) for idx, x in enumerate(df['X'])]
# [(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4)]
```

## Update - i.e., avoid the loop

```
l2 = list(zip(df.index, df['X'].sub([df['Y'].values]*len(df)).abs().agg(np.argmin)))
# [(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: First of all thanks, this does work, do you think this is the best solution in terms of efficiency? this takes approximately 3 seconds on my dataset and this needs to be done thousands of times

Comment: @OfekGlick see update to avoid the loop . . . should be quicker

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I managed to actually do this faster by converting the DF to a numpy array and used reshaping and broadcasting to calculated distances faster. When time allows I'll post another answer